# Network slows down and speeds up

Tags: networking

My laptop was connected to internet via wifi my router. Along with the laptop there was other computer connected with cable with router. Recently I saw some weird `access limited` sings on networking icon near system clock. I thought that it must be wifi problem as second computer had internet all the time.

But today I bypassed router and connected internet cable directly to the laptop. The internet was working, however it speeds up and slows down all the time:
[image: chart]

It's probably not the IPS throttling, because it never reaches my limit.

Comment: When on the cable what is your results on http://www.speedtest.net? (Does the needle vibrate the whole time or does it "stick" sometimes?) Also do you get dropped/lost packets when you do a `ping -n 10 google.com`? What is the maximum speed of your access (what you pay for) and what do you get?

Comment: The needle vibrates all the time. My internet speed is 2 Mbits, and I get what I pay for on second computer. This one just started acting strange.

Comment: What was the result of speednet? Is it close to your max? How did that graph look during the speedtest? What did you do during the original graph? If you speed is close to max and the graph is ok this time it's a problem with you original test. The fact that the needle vibrates the whole time is a good sign and indicates no dips in the test (assuming the graph during the test was also steady)

Comment: The result is below the half of my net speed. And needle was vibrating between my max speed and once even reached 0. I am pretty sure that's not the correct behaviour.

Comment: No, it should vibrate at about the same position. You could try a couple if things (all while on cable). Disable the virusscanner during test. Run the test in safe mode. Try a different cable (but that would not explain disruption in wifi). Scan your computer for malware (you could use [Anti-Malware Free](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) for this).